# Story involving fabbers (replicators / 3D-printers), famous quote

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to identify a short story involving replicators/fabbers/3D-printers. The devices use a carbon fiber that can be recycled, and that fact is important. I remember the use of the Harold McMillan quote:

"Tradition doesn't mean that the living are dead, but that the dead are living."

I seem to remember that it was a fairly prominent sci-fi author, but I cannot recall it. I think it was written post-2000; I read it online.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/QuotesPorn/comments/ko1j8z/blindly_following_tradition_does_not_mean_the/ seems to suggest an older (slightly different) quote FWIW.

Comment: And the McMillan statement may be "Tradition does not mean that the living are dead, it means that the dead are living"

Comment: :-P Not criticizing, just mentioning it since a common tactic for researching these things is looking for such exact phrases. Funnily enough, G.K. Chesterton has also been credited for originating that phrase.

Comment: I recall that the quote was delivered by one of the characters as if it was their thought.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Famous author, story about fabbers, this is likely "[Kiosk](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?204801)" (2007) by Bruce Sterling.

It deals with the introduction of fabbers from creating innocuous toys to, more or less, the destruction of the existing economic system.  It contains the required quote:

> Borislav touched a handkerchief to his lips. "Tradition does not mean that the living are dead. Tradition means that the dead are living."

Not much about recycling though, except to note at one point that the quick-and-dirty fabbers that are being hacked together don't do any recycling:

> They still had no recycling combs. That was bad. It confounded and betrayed the whole dream of fabs to make them with the nozzles but not the recycling combs. This meant that their outlaw fabs could make things, but never recycle them. A world with fabs like that would be a nightmare: it would slowly but surely fill up with horrible, polluting fabjunk: unusable, indestructible, rock-solid lumps of black slag. Clearly this dark prospect had much affected the counsels of the original inventors.

The story was originally published in *Fantasy & Science Fiction*, January 2007, and for a while was [available on their website](https://web.archive.org/web/20080115084153/http://www.sfsite.com/fsf/fiction/bs01.htm) (archived link).